# how flask-sqlalchemy turn off returning id while insert data

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert data to PostgreSQL 8.3.23 by Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2, the errors show that `INSERT statement is not supported in this version of Greenplum Database`.
so how can I turn off returning id in (flask-)sqlalchemy while insert.

```
class BU(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'bu'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    bu_code = db.Column(db.String(125), index=True, comment=u'some')
    bu = db.Column(db.String(125), nullable=False, comment=u'some')
    is_game = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, comment=u'some')
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0, info={'table_enums': [{'value': 0, 'text': u"some"}, {'value': 1, 'text': u"some"}]})
    add_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now, comment=u'some')
```

```
ipdb> res = BU(bu_code='333', bu='hello')
ipdb> db.session.add(res)
ipdb> db.session.flush()
*** NotSupportedError: (psycopg2.NotSupportedError) The RETURNING clause of the INSERT statement is not supported in this version of Greenplum Database.
 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO bu (bu_code, bu, is_game, status, add_time) VALUES (%(bu_code)s, %(bu)s, %(is_game)s, %(status)s, %(add_time)s) RETURNING bu.id'] [parameters: {'status': 0, 'bu': 'hello', 'is_game': False, 'bu_code': '333', 'add_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 24, 16, 53, 49, 613000)}] (Background on t
his error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/tw8g)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [implicit_returning](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.implicit_returning) [create_engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine) parameter to `False`.

```
engine = create_engine(url, implicit_returning=False)
```

> When True, a RETURNING- compatible construct, if available, will be used to fetch newly generated primary key values when a single row INSERT statement is emitted with no existing returning() clause. This applies to those backends which support RETURNING or a compatible construct, including PostgreSQL, Firebird, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server. Set this to False to disable the automatic usage of RETURNING.

Since version 2.4 Flask-SQLAlchemy provides a `SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS` configuration option to pass a dictionary of keyword arguments for engine creation, so you can do

```py
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {'implicit_returning': False}
```

*The following section applies to Flask-SQLAlchemy < 2.4, which had not been released when this answer was originally composed*

Flask-SQLAlchemy doesn't expose engine creation directly, it might be possible to override [SQLAlchemy.apply_driver_hacks](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.apply_driver_hacks) to inject the extra parameter.

> This method is called before engine creation and used to inject driver specific hacks into the options. The options parameter is a dictionary of keyword arguments that will then be used to call the sqlalchemy.create_engine() function.

There is an outstanding [pull-request](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/684) to expose a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me how use in flask-sqlalchemy.


I have try:
```
db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={"implicit_returning": False})
db.init_app(app)
```
but it doesn't work for me .

Comment: @pagala2008 I've added some information to the answer

Comment: [https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/67#issuecomment-33196525](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/pull/67#issuecomment-33196525)